# Rails partial not rendered when called via JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a partial upon change in the drop down list.
There is the onchange javascript function which directs to a link to display the corresponding form.

But here I am getting a `#<ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat>` error inside the get_template method in controller.

I suppose it is something to do with calling the link through javascript, as the request is processed as HTML.

```
Processing by XYZController#get_template as HTML
```

How to process it as JS ?

Here's the detailed code.

**dropdown.html.erb**

```
<div id="requests_dropdown">
Choose the type of request : <%= select_tag 'drop_request_id', options_for_select(@request_types.map{|x| [x[:name], x[:id]] } ) %>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

$('#drop_request_id').on('change', function() { 
  var request_type_id = $('#drop_request_id').val();
  var href =  'get_template/' + request_type_id ;
  window.location = href;
});
</script>
```

**controller**

```
   def get_template

    @request_type = [x,y,z] 
    respond_to do |format|
            format.js
    end
end
```

**get_template.js.erb**

```
$("#request_form_partial").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'request_form', locals: {  request_type: @request_type } ) %>");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `window.location = href` instead of an AJAX `get` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your method via ajax.
You are getting error because you are trying to GET the html format,whereas your method renders the js format response.

Please edit your code to following:

```
     <script> $('#drop_request_id').on('change', function() { 
var request_type_id = $('#drop_request_id').val(); 
var href = 'get_template.js/' + request_type_id ; 
$.get(href);
}); 
</script>
```